# How to model an exhaust fan?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, workflow

Looking for suggestions on how to model an exhaust fan. I would probably start with a cube and then draw splines for the indentations. Chamfer the edges of the spline so they are curved like in the picture. And then extrude the splines and use a boolean substract to cut into the cube.

One like this seems straight forward:

[image]
[image]

Please let me know if there is an eaiser way to do this.

One this like with a more organic shape I have no idea how to do. Do you have an suggestions on how to do this?

[image]

And finally this one I think I would use a boolean operation again to get all the holes. All the holes would be made from a basic cube. But what would be the best way to get that many cubes on an object? A cloner? Also how would I ensure that everything is symmetrical?

[image]

All suggestions are welcome and appreciated!

Comment: *Prof. Fansworth: Can you put that into a form of a question? Fry: Uh, what if that thing I just said?* - hello  this is a Q&A site - you don't really have to put a post in a form of a question with an explicit question mark, but it has to be a single, specific, answerable problem.

Comment: @B3rnard395 -- "what would be the best way to get that many cubes on an object": Answer: you can use two Array modifiers (one for the X axis clones, one for the Y axis) on the Cube you'll use in the boolean.

Comment: @james_t you can also inset the face for a margin, then subdivide, then inset individual faces (double "i" key) and x, f to remove faces

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For the first one, inset a face twice:

[image]

Then create edge loops with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>:

[image]

Bevel the 4 concentric edges with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>:

[image]

Select the face loops and extrude, etc:

[image]

For the second one, create this kind of shape:

[image]

Mirror it, array, give it a *Lattice* in order to deform, then extrude etc:

[image]

For the third, you can easily create holes in a grid.

Comment: Awesome thank you!  This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: you're welcome, next time please only ask one question and show the pictures in your question   ;)

Comment: If so, please mark it as accepted, thanks @B3rnard395 How this site works: https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: @moonboots -- excellant!  Is there some easy way to "Select the face loops"?  Seems like a tedious process to select so many, manually.

Comment: in edge select mode you could create the edge loops with Ctrl R then bevel with Ctrl B then keep the bevel selected then extrude

Comment: but selecting face loops is rather easy with Shift Alt right click